# Netbeans RCP - Deactivate modules by default

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I have a `Netbeans platform application` ,

where i have multiple modules installed. To **Deactivate** a particular module i  use `Tools -> Plugin` option in the application.

How can i **Deactivate** modules by default (when application is launched for first time) and only if user needs it he can **Activate** it using `Tools->Plugin`

Answer (score 0):

I am using the `ModuleInstall` `validate()` method and throwing an `IllegalStateException`, which makes the module to be loaded in **Deactivated** mode.

```
public class ModuleHandler extends ModuleInstall {

    @Override
    public void validate() {
            IllegalStateException e = new IllegalStateException();
            IllegalStateException attachLocalizedMessage = Exceptions.attachLocalizedMessage(e,
                    "* This Module will not be loaded.");
            throw attachLocalizedMessage;
        }
}
```

Source : [Module API](http://bits.netbeans.org/8.2/javadoc/org-openide-modules/org/openide/modules/doc-files/api.html)